# Dojo XHR don't send a request to other server at all, but everything works in jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, cross-domain

I have the development enviroment consisting of the Apache HTTP server for fast Javascript development and the application server (WebSphere) that provides the JSON REST API. Of course, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set (to *).

The following code results in error:

```
 xhr.post({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/rest-sample/rest/test/list",
  handleAs: "json",
  load: onload
 });

 RequestError: Unable to load
 http://localhost:8080/rest-sample/rest/test/list status: 0
 ErrorCtor()create.js (Zeile 13) onError()xhr.js (Zeile 80)     

 var err = Error.call(this, message),
```

There is a JavaScript error thrown instead of sending the AJAX request. However, in the same time, the following jQuery snipplet function perfect:

```
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/rest-sample/rest/test/list"
    $.post(url, {}, onLoad, 'json')
```

My question is: what I'm doing wrong? How to send the AJAX request to the other server using Dojo?

I'm using **dojo 1.9**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server must also send `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with`.

Comment: But the dojo client isn't sending any request, so how he can read the response?

Comment: You’re wrong. It *is* sending a request: a CORS preflight OPTIONS request. jQuery does too, but it omits the `x-requested-by` header when it detects a CORS request.

Comment: why I don't see the request in console? I must inspect it closer, I will try on Monday

Comment: Yes, this was it, DOJO is sending OPTIONS request, but it shows in Network tab, not in Console, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think xhr.post is no longer supported, i suggest to use dojo/request, or at least dojo/request/xhr

```
require(["dojo/request/xhr"], function(xhr){
  xhr("http://localhost/rest-sample/rest/test/list", {
    handleAs: "json",
    method: "POST"
  }).then(function(data){
    // Do something with the handled data
  }, function(err){
    // Handle the error condition
  }, function(evt){
    // Handle a progress event from the request if the
    // browser supports XHR2
  });
});
```

If it's Cross origin problem i would suggest using ReverseProxy on your http server.

add this to your httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass /rest-sample/ http://localhost:8080/rest-sample/
```

Comment: Thanx for new syntax, but the situation is quite the same: my onerr function is called, and exactly the same error message: '

RequestError: Unable to load http://localhost:8080/rest-sample/rest/test/list status: 0'

Comment: well, the cross origin is not a problem, because on jQuery it works, so the problem is the Dojo don't want to call that.

Comment: status: 0 indicates that responseText is empty, do you return anything?

Comment: not request is sent, for sure! Firebug shows that no request is made.